# Select two certain values of a column in R RStudio

Tags: r, select, filter, subset

It is about the dataset MplsStops from R.

I have selected two column of the dataset I need: race and citationIssued.

After that, I omitted all NAs.

Then I want to filter all citationIssued values by the values Black and White from the column race.

How can I get done that?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The `dplyr` package is your friend if you are trying to learn data processing with `R`.

How about this:

```
library(carData)  # get the sample data

library(dplyr)  # load dplyr for data processing functions
MplsStops %>%  # start with the data and pipe it to the next line
  select(race, citationIssued) %>%  #  keep two variables and pipe to next line
  filter(race %in% c("Black", "White") & !is.na(citationIssued))
```

If that answers it click the green checkmark and if not add a comment for more help.